# Render Layer Compositing - Get closest pixel to camera

Tags: compositing-nodes, depth-map

I'm creating something like a depth map material. I tried Camera Data approaches but I could not get what I wanted.

Render Layer Compositing is working better, but I'm try to normalize in a slightly different way. Traditional normalize spreads the values over the range 0-1, but this changes the 'scale'. I need to just shift the values to the edge of the range 0-1, as I'd like the closest point to the camera to be white. This could be done with simple addition but I need to know how much to add, i.e, the smallest depth value.

I tried using depth->minimum node but I was getting either all white or all black.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might try plugging Depth into Normalize -> ColorRamp. Then you can adjust the ramp to your liking?

[image]

You could also try using the "Mist" pass. Enable that render pass and set the distance of the mist in the world panel. You can set the camera to show the mist pass distance in the viewport. The mist pass is already normalized (0-1.0), so you can plug it directly into a ColorRamp.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little short on time, so I decided to just output the raw depth image in TIFF format and transform it using python to meet my needs.